# If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$ then $e^f$ is

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, exponential-function, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$. I want to show that $e^f$ is also integrable.

I see that $e^f$ is nonnegative, so $\int_0 ^1 e^f$ is defined as an exteded real number.

If $f$ were bounded, say $|f| <M$, I would observe that $\int_0 ^1 e^f \leq \int_0 ^1 e^M=e^M< \infty$ and be done. However, $f$ might not be bounded in general.

Comment: False, look at $f(x)=1/\sqrt x.$

Comment: Another comment: An $L^1$ function can be unbounded. If so, then $e^f$ will be way more unbounded than $f.$ That's how you want to start thinking about these situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. Consider $f(x) : = \ln(1/x)$. Then 
$$
\int_{0}^1 \ln(1/x) \, dx = x + x \log(1/x) \Bigg|_{x = 0}^{x = 1} = 1.
$$
Hence $f$ is Lebesgue integrable. On the other hand, 
$$
\int_{0}^1 e^{f(x)} \, dx = \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{x} \, dx 
$$
does not converge.